# webform validation integer value

Tags: webforms, forms

I tried [webform validation](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_validation), I can validate textfield component for numeric value.
However, I cannot find how to set it as integer value only.
How can I validate numeric (integer) value.

Comment: By "how to set it as integer value", do you mean you're looking to store the internal PHP webform data as an int instead of a string?

Comment: To limit user submission in the textfield component as integer value only. When I use webform validation (for example "1|100") the submission 1.5 can be accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Webform Validation's [numeric validator](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/webform_validation/tree/webform_validation.validators.inc#n454) relies on PHP's [is_numeric](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php). Thus, any numeric expression (e.g. 1.5) is going to be validated there. In order to validate integers only, you'll need to use Regex validation where only integers character can be valid (e.g. "^([0-9]+)$").

Comment: Thank you, that's perfect, this what I want. I did not realize there is regular expression and I did not know the code. Now I can set to accept only 1 to 1000 and integer only in the textfield component. The webform validation to the field: Numeric values "1|1000" and Regular expression "^([0-9]+)$"